# Is there a way to extract email addresses from a distribution list via command line in Outlook?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have been able to get the members of the distro list via the command below but I am unable to figure out how to get the email addresses. Any ideas?

dsquery group -name "Distribution-list" | dsget group -members -expand

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the email addresses and also expand the distribution group for subgroups.

```
dsquery group -name "group name"|dsget group -members -expand|dsquery user |dsget user -dn -samid -email
```

[Reference](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH38738&key=15244&actp=LIST)